# How to delete .cleverfiles created by Disk Drill

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, disk-space, third-party

I found this folder called `.cleverfiles` and it takes over 130 Gb of space on my MacBook. I found it accidentally but before I deleted it I went to check what this folder is then I lost its path and I can't find it again. Can anyone help me, please? I did uninstall Disk Drill safely but the folder remains, hidden, and I can't search for it. This folder is actually created to save deleted files so you can recover them again.

[image: Screenshot of the location of the folder .cleverfiles using the app Disk Cartography]

Comment: Already tried to reveal hidden files with "Shift + Command + ." first and then searched for it!?

Comment: I did solve this problem, thanks for reaching out